# Look for cell within a data frame and replace its value without loops R

Tags: r, dplyr

Using this df:

```
  DF = data.frame(m=rep(1:2,2), y=rep(1998:1999,each=2), A=c(2:5), B=c(4,NA,6,7))

> DF
  m    y A  B
1 1 1998 2  4
2 2 1998 3 NA
3 1 1999 4  6
4 2 1999 5  7
```

How could I replace a single cell using as coordinates this values:

```
m = 2 ; y = 1999 ; col = 'A' ; val = 72
```

Following those values I want to replace 5 with 72.

---

**Edit.**
As testing all the answers I realized my question is very basic and don't represent my problem. I tried to do it without for loops but failed and eventually used it.

So, I want to replace values within the `DF` data frame but using this other data frame:

```
repl = data.frame(m=c(2,1), y=c(1999,1998), col=c('A','B'), val=c(72,100))
> repl
  m    y col val
1 2 1999   A  72
2 1 1998   B 100
```

This means that each row of the `repl` data frame is a value to replace in `DF`.

I've been trying to use Psidom answer `mutate(A = replace(A, m == 2 & y == 1999, 72)` for each row but wonder if can be done without loops or without using column names.

Thank you.

Comment: `df$A[df$m==2 & df$y==1999] <- 72`

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` way is `mutate` + `if_else`:

```
DF %>% mutate(A = if_else(m == 2 & y == 1999, 72L, A))

#  m    y  A  B
#1 1 1998  2  4
#2 2 1998  3 NA
#3 1 1999  4  6
#4 2 1999 72  7
```

---

Or `mutate` + `replace`:

```
DF %>% mutate(A = replace(A, m == 2 & y == 1999, 72))

#  m    y  A  B
#1 1 1998  2  4
#2 2 1998  3 NA
#3 1 1999  4  6
#4 2 1999 72  7
```

which depending on the condition, returns a new vector with intended values replaced.

---

*Update* if you need to do many updates at the same time, you can:

1) reshape `DF` so the columns to be updated get gathered in a single column;

2) join on the two condition columns `m` and `y` plus the column headers column;

3) update the values;

4) reshape the data frame back;

So together with `tidyr`, you can do:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
    gather(col, vals, -m, -y) %>% 
    left_join(repl, by = c("m", "y", "col")) %>% 
    mutate(vals = coalesce(val, vals)) %>% 
    select(-val) %>% 
    spread(col, vals)

#  m    y  A   B
#1 1 1998  2 100
#2 1 1999  4   6
#3 2 1998  3  NA
#4 2 1999 72   7
```

Comment: Great. How would it be with indexes rather than column names? Should I do `DF %>% mutate(.[3] = replace(.[3], m == 2 & y == 1999, 72))` ?

Comment: You can use `mutate_at` and pass the column positions to `.var` variable. `DF %>% mutate_at(.vars = 3, funs(replace(., m == 2 & y == 1999, 72)))`.

Comment: Nice. What if there are more than one column to work with? I mean: replace m=2, y=1999, col='A' with 72 **and** m=1, y=1998, col='B' with 100

Comment: In that case, you will probably have to write two replace statements as `mutate(A = replace(A, m == 2 & y == 1999, 72), B = replace(B, m == 1 & y == 1998, 100))`.

Comment: Ok. I edited the question as I noticed there are many replacements I have to do and tried to put the question in a more general way.

Answer (score 1):

A one-line method in base-R for your follow up question would be

```
lapply(1:nrow(repl), function(i) 
       DF[DF$m==repl$m[i] & DF$y==repl$y[i], repl$col[i]] <<- repl$val[i])

DF
  m    y  A   B
1 1 1998  2 100
2 2 1998  3  NA
3 1 1999  4   6
4 2 1999 72   7
```

This goes through each row of `repl` and makes the changes to `DF`. The `<<-` forces it to make the changes to the original `DF` in the global environment.